# The "from" field has been defined when sending a transaction, but the error still occurs

Tags: solidity, metamask, react

**Problem**

I am following [this tutorial](https://cryptojobslist.com/blog/how-to-add-ethereum-payments-to-your-site-with-metamask) on how to make a donate button on my React app. The tutorial is in HTML, however, so below is my attempt at converting it to ReactJS.

**Code**

*App.jsx*

```
donate = () => {
  const donationAddress = "0x...";

  web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    to: donationAddress,
    value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether")
  }, (err, transactionId) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Donation failed", err);
      alert("Donation failed.");
    } else {
      console.log("Donation successful", transactionId);
      alert("Donation successful!");
    }
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Donate</p>
      <button onClick={this.donate}>Donate 1 wei</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I commented out the two lines of code above from the tutorial because I had received this error: `TypeError: web3__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.toWei is not a function`.

**Output**

Initially, I don't receive an error on the page until I click the button. Then I receive this error: `The send transactions "from" field must be defined!`.

It highlights this line as the error: `web3.eth.sendTransaction({`.

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Is there any chance that `accounts.length == 0` hence `accounts[0] === undefined`?

Comment: BTW, function `web3.toWei` is on web3.js v0.x. On web3.js v1.x, it is function `web3.utils.toWei`.

Comment: @goodvibration, thanks for your second comment, I updated it with `utils` in it and that error disappeared. However, I did get a different error.

Comment: This is the error I received: `Please pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors.`

Comment: So what part of this error is not clear to you???

Comment: Nvm, fixed it. I still receive this though: `Error: The send transactions "from" field must be defined!` I've updated the code in the post.

Comment: You have not referred to my first comment. What is `accounts[0]`???

Comment: It's `undefined`.

Comment: Well? Do you still have a problem understanding the error-message?

Comment: Nvm, fixed it! Thank you so much @goodvibration!

Answer (score 0):

Updated code. Thanks @goodvibration!

```
  donate = async () => {
    const donationAddress = "0x...";

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    this.setState({ account: accounts[0] });

    web3.eth.sendTransaction({
      to: donationAddress,
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether")
    }, (err, transactionId) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Donation failed", err);
        alert("Donation failed.");
      } else {
        console.log("Donation successful", transactionId);
        alert("Donation successful!");
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: What's the point in `web3.utils.toWei("1", "wei")`? You may as well just use `"1"`.

Comment: Edited, that was a mistake; I was experimenting with different values after looking it up in the docs.